# Set Windows 7 to "Performance optimized" under Visual Effects with Batch script

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, performance, batch

I have this .bat script to start a specific game:

```
@echo off
if not "%~1"=="p" start /min cmd.exe /c %0 p&exit
start "" "GTAVLauncher.exe"
timeout /t 60 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /f /im GTAVLauncher.exe
wmic process where name="GTAVLauncher.exe" CALL setpriority "low priority"
wmic process where name="GTA5.exe" CALL setpriority "high priority"
pause
```

What I want to do is to set Windows 7 to "Performance optimized" under the "Visual Effects" tab when the batch script starts (it needs to be the first command executed, so before the GTA5Launcher.exe start) until the game exe file ends (it need to watch somehow the GTA5.exe) and than set it back to normal, which is "best appearance". is it possible somehow?

Comment: possibly stop the service UxSms ?

Comment: Can you describe what is this service?

Comment: the desktop window manager

Comment: I read that this will disable aero. Is it possible to write a script that's watching end of the GTA5.exe and than re-enable aero again?

Comment: With this standalone script maybe?
http://superuser.com/questions/209676/how-to-quickly-enable-and-adisable-aero-in-windows-7

Comment: just run the service again